# XSLT generic solution to get hierarchical html table out of XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

The xml format is a good way to store any hierarchical data. As an example we are using the classification of animals

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<classificationOfAnimals>
    <vertebrates>
        <warmBlooded>
            <mammals>
                <bear>
                    <individualNamedPeter/>
                    <individualNamedTed/>
                </bear>
                <tiger/>
                <whale/>
            </mammals>
            <birds>
                <ostrich/>
                <peacock/>
                <eagle/>
            </birds>
        </warmBlooded>
        <coldBlooded>
            <fish>
                <salmon/>
                <goldfish/>
                <guppy/>
            </fish>
            <reptiles>
                <turtle/>
                <crocodile/>
                <snake/>                
            </reptiles>
            <amphibians>
                <frog/>
                <toad/>
                <newt/>
            </amphibians>
        </coldBlooded>
    </vertebrates>
    <invertebrates>
        <withJoinedLegs>
            <with3PairsOfLegs>
                <ant/>
                <cockroch>
                    <fatherDan>
                        <sonBob>
                            <bruce/>
                            <lenny/>
                            <susan/>
                        </sonBob>
                    </fatherDan>
                </cockroch>
                <ladybug/>
            </with3PairsOfLegs>
            <withMoreThan3PairsOfLegs>
                <scorpion/>
                <spider/>
                <millipede/>
            </withMoreThan3PairsOfLegs>
        </withJoinedLegs>
        <withoutLegs>
            <wormLike>
                <earthworm/>
                <leech/>
            </wormLike>
            <notWormLike>
                <flukeWorm>
                    <individualNamedLance/>
                </flukeWorm>                
                <tapeWorm/>
            </notWormLike>
        </withoutLegs>
    </invertebrates>
</classificationOfAnimals>
```

Out of this xml data I want to create a html table which represents the hierarchy of the animal classification.

As a result I want a table like this
[image: tableAnimalClassification]

The transformation shall be done with XSLT and it should be a generic approach, which can handle any kind of hierarchy, no matter how many rows and columns are needed or if the table has to be jagged or how deep the hierarchy is.
The general problem which we have here, is that the html table will not have the hierarchical structure like the xml does. A html table just consists out of rows and columns. To get a hierarchical structure like in the screenshot we need to use the attribute `rowspan` for the `td` element of the table. With this attribute a cell is spanned over several rows.
As a result we need a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="28">classificationOfAnimals</td>
        <td rowspan="16">vertebrates</td>
        <td rowspan="7">warmBlooded</td>
        <td rowspan="4">mammals</td>
        <td rowspan="2">bear</td>
        <td>individualNamedPeter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>individualNamedTed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tiger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>whale</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">birds</td>
        <td>ostrich</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>peacock</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>eagle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="9">coldBlooded</td>
        <td rowspan="3">fish</td>
        <td>salmon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>goldfish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>guppy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">reptiles</td>
        <td>turtle</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>crocodile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>snake</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">amphibians</td>
        <td>frog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>toad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>newt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="12">invertebrates</td>
        <td rowspan="8">withJoinedLegs</td>
        <td rowspan="5">with3PairsOfLegs</td>
        <td>ant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">cockroch</td>
        <td rowspan="3">fatherDan</td>
        <td rowspan="3">sonBob</td>
        <td>bruce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lenny</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>susan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ladybug</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">withMoreThan3PairsOfLegs</td>
        <td>scorpion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>spider</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>millipede</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">withoutLegs</td>
        <td rowspan="2">wormLike</td>
        <td>earthworm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>leech</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">notWormLike</td>
        <td rowspan="1">flukeWorm</td>
        <td>individualNamedLance</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tapeWorm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you really sure it's a good idea to have individual species as element names? Normally I'd expect to see something more like `<species name="cockroach"/>` rather than `<cockroach>` - or perhaps phylum/kingdom/genus or whatever in place of species.

Comment: Yeah you are right, in my original implementation which I use for my special purpose there I have a just a couple of different element names and the distinction is made by the name attribute. But this does not make a difference for the XSLT, I have just replaced @name by name(...). I wanted just a simple xml as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we can see in the html table, is that the first row holds a cell for every hierarchy level which is represented as a column. This means it has to be generated a row with all elements from the highest till the deepest hierarchy level. The element on the deepest hierarchy level is the one without further descendants. To get these we can use this xpath expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="./descendant::*[not(./descendant::*)]">
```

This means get all descendants which have no descendants itself.
Then we are on the deepest hierarchy level and we can build up the row from behind, from the deepest to the highest level. So now we need to get the ancestors of this deepest element. But only if the deepest element, which is currently in the scope, is the first child of its parent, which is `individualNamedPeter` in the example, because `tiger` and following have to be in a single row.

```
<!-- is the element the first child of its parent -->
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(parent::*/*[1])">
```

Then to fill up the row from behind with the ancestors to get `bear`, `mammals`, `warmBlooded`, `vertebrates` and `classificationOfAnimals` we will use a recursively called template

```
 <!-- in the row with the first child of its parent we need as well the ancestors -->
 <xsl:call-template name="printTheAncestors">                        
     <xsl:with-param name="ancestors" select="./ancestor-or-self::*"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

The passed parameter are all ancestor-or-self elements

```
<xsl:template name="printTheAncestors">
    <xsl:param name="ancestors"/>
    <xsl:param name="positionNumber" select="count($ancestors)"/>

    <!-- we need only the ancestor if the previous ancestor is the first child of this ancestor -->
    <xsl:if test="generate-id($ancestors[$positionNumber]) = generate-id($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1]/*[1])">

        <xsl:call-template name="printTheAncestors">
            <xsl:with-param name="ancestors" select="$ancestors"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="positionNumber" select="$positionNumber - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>            

        <!-- we are getting here the right order of the elements, because after the end of the recursive calling -->
        <!-- the nested called templates are returning one after another from the last to the first call  -->
        <td>
            <!-- the ancestor td cell has to span the count of rows which are holding descendants without further descendants -->
            <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="count($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1]/descendant::*[not(./descendant::*)])"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:value-of select="name($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1])"/>

        </td>  

    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Inside this template we want again the ancestor only if the previous ancestor is the first child of the current ancestor, because we want to create e.g. the `td` `warmBlooded` just in the row where we have `mammals` and not in the row with `birds`. And furthermore we need to stop the recursion when we have found the first ancestor where the previous ancestor is not its first child. Because e.g. when we are iterating over `birds` we do not want to create a `td` for `vertebrates` although `warmBlooded` is the first child of `vertebrates`, so we need to stop at `birds` during iteration over `birds`.

With `$positionNumber - 1` it is climbed up from ancestor to ancestor, from the deepest to the highest.

A further challenge is the order how the `td` are printed. Because the checking of the ancestors is done starting at the deepest. But to get the desired table we need the `td` `classificationOfAnimals` as the first element and so on. This is achieved by placing the `td` block after the recursive calling of the template. This leads to the result that the recursive called templates are returning one after another when the condition is not fulfilled anymore and so the `td` of the first called template is printed last and vice versa.

The last thing that we need to do is to determine the rowspan for each element.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1]/descendant::*[not(./descendant::*)])"/>
```

**Full stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>


    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html>

            <head>
                <title>Hierarchical html table out of xml</title>                
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../whereIsWhichAttributeUsed.css"/>
            </head>

            <body>

                <h1>Hierarchical html table out of xml</h1>

                <div>                
                    <table>
                        <!-- we need a row for each element which has no further descendants -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="./descendant::*[not(./descendant::*)]">
                            <tr>
                                <!-- is the element the first child of its parent -->
                                <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(parent::*/*[1])">
                                    <!-- in the row with the first child of its parent we need as well the ancestors -->
                                    <xsl:call-template name="printTheAncestors">                        
                                        <xsl:with-param name="ancestors" select="./ancestor-or-self::*"/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:if>

                                <!-- the lonely descendant without descendants -->
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="printTheAncestors">
        <xsl:param name="ancestors"/>
        <xsl:param name="positionNumber" select="count($ancestors)"/>

        <!-- we need only the ancestor if the previous ancestor is the first child of this ancestor -->
        <xsl:if test="generate-id($ancestors[$positionNumber]) = generate-id($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1]/*[1])">

            <xsl:call-template name="printTheAncestors">
                <xsl:with-param name="ancestors" select="$ancestors"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="positionNumber" select="$positionNumber - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>            

            <!-- we are getting here the right order of the elements, because after the end of the recursive calling -->
            <!-- the nested called templates are returning one after another from the last to the first call  -->
            <td>
                <!-- the ancestor td cell has to span the count of rows which are holding descendants without further descendants -->
                <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
                    <xsl:value-of select="count($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1]/descendant::*[not(./descendant::*)])"/>
                </xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:value-of select="name($ancestors[$positionNumber - 1])"/>

            </td>  

        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML output**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Hierarchical html table out of xml</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../whereIsWhichAttributeUsed.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hierarchical html table out of xml</h1>
      <div>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="28">classificationOfAnimals</td>
               <td rowspan="16">vertebrates</td>
               <td rowspan="7">warmBlooded</td>
               <td rowspan="4">mammals</td>
               <td rowspan="2">bear</td>
               <td>individualNamedPeter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>individualNamedTed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>tiger</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>whale</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">birds</td>
               <td>ostrich</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>peacock</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>eagle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="9">coldBlooded</td>
               <td rowspan="3">fish</td>
               <td>salmon</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>goldfish</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>guppy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">reptiles</td>
               <td>turtle</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>crocodile</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>snake</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">amphibians</td>
               <td>frog</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>toad</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>newt</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="12">invertebrates</td>
               <td rowspan="8">withJoinedLegs</td>
               <td rowspan="5">with3PairsOfLegs</td>
               <td>ant</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">cockroch</td>
               <td rowspan="3">fatherDan</td>
               <td rowspan="3">sonBob</td>
               <td>bruce</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>lenny</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>susan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>ladybug</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="3">withMoreThan3PairsOfLegs</td>
               <td>scorpion</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>spider</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>millipede</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="4">withoutLegs</td>
               <td rowspan="2">wormLike</td>
               <td>earthworm</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>leech</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="2">notWormLike</td>
               <td rowspan="1">flukeWorm</td>
               <td>individualNamedLance</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>tapeWorm</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that code run with an XSLT 2 processor as the version attribute suggests? The generate-id checks seem XSLT 1 like.

Comment: I have used the Saxon processor but XSLT 2 is not necessary. The attribute was just a legacy from another stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can just walk the parent axis with your condition about making sure you are processing the first child of its parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style xsl:expand-text="no">
        table, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[not(*)]" mode="leaf"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="leaf">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*[current() is current()/../*[1]]"/>
      <td>{name()}</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*[current() is current()/../*[1]]"/>
    <td rowspan="{count(descendant::*[not(*)])}">{name()}</td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used XSLT 3 as that leads to more compact and readable code but in the end the templates could be written the same for XSLT 1 using the `generate-id()` comparison instead of `is` and `xsl:value-of` instead of the text value template.

Comment: Yes we get the same result. I had a similar solution before. But because first I did not get it to change the order of the elements from the highest to the deepest level by placing the `td` element after the calling of the templates, and to rely on the returning of the called templates in the reversed order, I have tought I would need to store the ancestors in one variable to switch the order. And as I get it with the correct placing of `td` I still kept it that way with the ancestors.